# Error with addstoredproc method in cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am calling a stored procedure with cfscript, but when I add the `addProcResult` method to the call, ColdFusion returns the error *The specified key, result, does not exist in the structure.* Removing the method fixes the error and doesn't effect the results, but I still would like to know why the error appeared. Using `<cfstoredproc>` and `<cfprocparam>` doesn't generate the error. I am running CF9. My code is below.

```
spService = new storedProc();
spService.setDatasource("mydb");
spService.setProcedure("someSP");
spService.setUsername("TaskRunner");
spService.setPassword("password");
spService.addProcResult(name="result",resultset=1);
spService.execute();
```

Comment: Does the Stored Procedure actually return a resultset? Or does it return its response via an Output Parameter? Procs can do both (or neither!)...but if it only does the latter--you're not going to get a resultset, and therefore, will have nothing to pour into, which may explain why you get no error after removing the call to save/store the "resultset that doesn't exist"

Comment: The proc doesn't return a resultset or an output. So I guess that makes sense, but why doesn't it error when using the tag?

Comment: My guess is: Backwards compatibility with previous versions of CF. Seeing as how 9 added support for script-based proc calls, they had flexibility to throw more dramatic errors when silliness occurred--but do not have that luxury with the CF tags. Coincidentally, if you instantiate a java object and call a method that returns a NULL while attempting to CFSET a var to its result, you'll get an "Variable is Undefined error" when you try to read it--even though its clear from code you called the CFSET. Similar sort of issue--the CFSET still goes through--but what it contains is non-existent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get this error if your stored procedure *actually doesn't return a resultset* (perhaps it returns an output parameter--or nothing at all).

Simply remove the call to .addProcResult(), and you'll be fine.